# makedict in ICS keyboard

Tags: android, dictionary, keyboard, binary, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich

I tried to use main.dict from the Gingerbread keyboard but it's not working. Then I tried to makedict from xml file to main.dict base on ICS source code. The problem is if the word in the XML file is not much (10-20) I can use it, but if I try to add more it has an error saying "cannot open resource file". Logcat said it has been compressed. I don't know why or how to fix it.

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out that in raw folder ICS will compress everything if they didn't know file extension. So that is my main problem.

If you have binary dict for android keyboard, you should rename it from main.dict to main.mp3 or other extension that android recognizes.